# Keycloak: Custom login page with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, react-forms

I'm new to Keycloak and I was wondering if it is possible to have a custom login page made with React which can have an authentication on Keycloak or if I could customize Keycloak login page with a React form.

A little help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: There is a react project [Keycloakify](https://github.com/keycloakify/keycloakify) That you could look into!